# What does (size + 7) & ~7 mean?

Tags: c, bit-manipulation

I'm reading the Multiboot2 specification. You can find it [here](http://nongnu.askapache.com/grub/phcoder/multiboot.pdf). Compared to the previous version, it names all of its structures "tags". They're defined like this:

> #### 3.1.3 General tag structure
>
> Tags constitutes a buffer of structures following each other padded on `u_virt` size. Every structure has
>   following format:
>
> ```
>     +-------------------+
> u16 | type              |
> u16 | flags             |
> u32 | size              |
>     +-------------------+
> ```
>
> `type` is divided into 2 parts. Lower contains an identifier of
>   contents of the rest of the tag. `size` contains the size of tag
>   including header fields. If bit `0` of `flags` (also known as
>   `optional`) is set if bootloader may ignore this tag if it lacks
>   relevant support. Tags are terminated by a tag of type `0` and size
>   `8`.

Then later in example code:

```
for (tag = (struct multiboot_tag *) (addr + 8);
     tag->type != MULTIBOOT_TAG_TYPE_END;
     tag = (struct multiboot_tag *) ((multiboot_uint8_t *) tag
     + ((tag->size + 7) & ~7)))
```

The last part confuses me. In Multiboot 1, the code was substantially simpler, you could just do `multiboot_some_structure * mss = (multiboot_some_structure *) mbi->some_addr` and get the members directly, without confusing code like this.

Can somebody explain what `((tag->size + 7) & ~7)` means?

Comment: It returns a rounded `size` up, if needed, to a multiple of 8.

Comment: You must understand two concepts.  First, it requires you to know how bitwise operators work.   Assuming you can follow the logic of the using ~ and &, you then need to understand what it is doing and why it works.  A combination of the answer below explain the bitwise logic for the first part.  Then other  answers explain that the program as a whole performs rounding in multiples of 8 for the second part.

Comment: @jaybers Although the code would benefit with a comment.  the magic number of 7 is all ready a thing to avoid.  Code should have dropped bit fiddling, casting and magic numbers and used `tag += (tag->size + sizeof *tag -1)/sizeof *tag;`, with a comment.  ( Now see that comment is gone.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As mentioned by chux in his comment, this rounds `tag->size` up to the nearest multiple of 8.

Let's take a closer look at how that works.

Suppose `size` is 16:

```
 00010000         // 16 in binary
+00000111         // add 7
 --------
 00010111         // results in 23
```

The expression `~7` takes the value `7` and inverts all bits.  So:

```
 00010111         // 23 (from pervious step)
&11111000         // bitwise-AND ~7
 --------
 00010000         // results in 16
```

Now suppose `size` is 17:

```
 00010001         // 17 in binary
+00000111         // add 7
 --------
 00011000         // results in 24
```

Then:

```
 00011000         // 24 (from pervious step)
&11111000         // bitwise-AND ~7
 --------
 00011000         // results in 24
```

So if the lower 3 bits of `size` are all zero, i.e. a multiple of 8, `(size+7)&~7` sets those bits and then clears them, so no net effect.  But if any one of those bits is 1, the bit corresponding to 8 gets incremented, then the lower bits are cleared, i.e. the number is rounded up to the nearest multiple of 8.

Answer (score 3):

~ is a bitwise not.  & is a bitwise AND
assuming 16 bits are used:

> 7 is 0000 0000 0000 0111
>
> ~7 is 1111 1111 1111 1000

Anything and'd with a 0 is 0.  Anything and'd with 1 is itself.  Thus

> N & 0 = 0
>
> N & 1 = N

So when you AND with ~7, you essentially clear the lowest three bits and all of the other bits remain unchanged.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for @chux for the answer. According to him, it rounds the `size` up to a multiple of 8, if needed. This is very similar to a technique done in 15bpp drawing code:

```
//+7/8 will cause this to round up...
uint32_t vbe_bytes_per_pixel = (vbe_bits_per_pixel + 7) / 8;
```

Here's the reasoning:

> Things were pretty simple up to now but some confusion is introduced
>   by the 16bpp format. It's actually 15bpp since the default format is
>   actually RGB 5:5:5 with the top bit of each u_int16 being unused. In
>   this format, each of the red, green and blue colour components is
>   represented by a 5 bit number giving 32 different levels of each and
>   32786 possible different colours in total (true 16bpp would be RGB
>   5:6:5 where there are 65536 possible colours). No palette is used for
>   16bpp RGB images - the red, green and blue values in the pixel are
>   used to define the colours directly.

Answer (score 1):

`& ~7` sets the last three bits to 0